# Get element event listener and store it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, listener

I want to remove an event listener from an element and later assign it back. Is there a way to get it and store in a variable smth like `var storedListener = Element.getEventListener('click')`, so that later I can do something like `Element.addEventListener('click', storedListener)`?

**UPDATE**

Listener is assigned inside template, I use Angular 2. It's

```
<div *ngFor="let entry of data; let i=index">
  <div class="element-description" (click)="editElementDescription(i)">{{entry.description}}</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to make contents of inside `<div>` an `<input>` after I click it, so that I can change value and send it to server. And inside `editElementDescription()` I do the following:

```
public editElementDescription(index: number): void {
    var elementDescription: HTMLDivElement = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementsByClassName('element-description')[index];
    elementDescription.removeEventListener('click');
    elementDescription.innerHTML = '<input id="change-description-input" type="text" value="' + elementDescription.innerHTML + '"/>';
  }
```

I remove that `click` listener because otherwise contents of `<input>` will get that `innerHTML` if I click it one more time. So the idea is to assign that `<input>` element a `change` listener, which will replace `<input>` by it's value and bring the parent `<div>` it's original listener back.

Comment: Your call to `elementDescription.removeEventListener` is invalid since this method takes 2 arguments. You need to pass a direct reference to the listener function as second argument.

Comment: Now I got your situation (after edit). But I suggest another approach: instead of controlling your events, you can use `data-` attribute to control your element state. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, i guess i'll just introduce a local variable for the component, which will be `boolean` for clicked condition and depending on that html template will show either `<a>` with value or `<input>`, controlled by `*ngIf`. Thx for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove a listener added with [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you must **keep track** of the listener function reference and remove it later with [`.removeEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

Something like that:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var btn_add = document.getElementById('btn-add-listener');
var btn_remove = document.getElementById('btn-remove-listener');

var fnListener =  function(e) {
    alert('Clicked!');
};


btn_add.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.addEventListener('click', fnListener);
});

btn_remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
    btn.removeEventListener('click', fnListener);
});
```

### Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/k5m1nog3/

---

## Other approach (added after question update)

Considering your actual problem, I suggest another approach: instead of handle events, you can set a `data-` attribute in the element indicating it's open. Then you just modify your inner HTML if the attribute is not present.

Something like this:

```
function editElementDescription(index) {

    var elementDescription = document.getElementsByClassName('element-description')[index];

    var isOpen = elementDescription.getAttribute('data-isOpen');

    if (!isOpen) {
      elementDescription.setAttribute('data-isOpen', 'true');
      elementDescription.innerHTML = '<input id="change-description-input" type="text" value="' + elementDescription.innerHTML + '"/>';

    }

}
```

### Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/e0yrL08v/

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it a bit wrong... there is no list of event listeners accessible from JavaScript... the only thing you can do is to remove/add an event if you know the origin.

There are 2 functions to manipulate event listeners:

1. addEventListener(event_type,function);
2. removeEventListener(event_type,function);

One object can have multiple events of same type... the only way to distinguish them is by giving an exact function being called.

Please note that if it's `jQuery`, it is possible, as it has own event stack... example below:

```
var events = $("#object1").data('events');
var $object2 = $("#object2");
if (events) {
    for(var eventType in events){
        for(var idx in events[eventType]){
            $object2[eventType](events[eventType][idx].handler);
        }
        $('#object1').off(eventType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible since [`.getEventListener` is only available for debugging purposes](https://codepen.io/azaslavsky/pen/sybfE).
There is unfortunately no way in standard JavaScript to programmatically get back the `EventListeners` attached to an object, and any library that tries to accomplish this will rely on unstable non-standard interfaces that may be discontinued any day.

So if your goal was to manipulate the listeners added by a library you have no control over, you're out of luck.
 On the other hand if you control the environment then you can store a reference to the attached callback if you want to attach the same listener to multiple objects, or remove it afterwards with [`.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

You could actually monkey-patch `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` to support this before anything else runs on your page, that wouldn't be a very clean solution to whatever problem you are having but if you think you really need to, here is a quick imperfect implementation of it (doesn't support `useCapture` argument):

```
// getEventListener polyfill, run this before anything else on your page.
(function monkeyPatchGetEventListeners(EventTarget) {

  const eventListeners = new WeakMap();

  const origAddEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
  EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function patchedAddEventListener(eventType, listener, ...args) {
    let allListeners;
    if (eventListeners.has(this)) {
      allListeners = eventListeners.get(this);
    } else {
      allListeners = new Map();
      eventListeners.set(this, allListeners);
    }

    let listeners;
    if (allListeners.has(eventType)) {
      listeners = allListeners.get(eventType);
    } else {
      listeners = [];
      allListeners.set(eventType, listeners);
    }

    listeners.push(listener);
    return origAddEventListener.call(this, eventType, listener,...args);
  }

  const origRemoveEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener;
  EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function patchedRemoveEventListener(eventType, listener, ...args) {
    const call = () => origRemoveEventListener(eventType, listener, useCapture, ...args);
    const allListeners = eventListeners.get(this);
    if (!allListeners) { return call(); }
    const listeners = allListeners.get(this);
    if (!listeners) { return call(); }
    const index = listeners.indexOf(listener);
    if (index === -1) { return call(); }
    index.splice(index, 1);
    return call();
  }

  EventTarget.prototype.getEventListeners = function patchedGetEventListeners(eventType) {
    const allListeners = eventListeners.get(this);
    return allListeners && allListeners.get(eventType);
  }
})(EventTarget);
```

Comment: *store a reference to the listener id returned by .addEventListener* Actually, `.addEventListener` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @mrlew You are totally right... bit of a brainfart right there.